# .htaccess RewriteRule does not work with "/"

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect my web page from `http://example.com/page.php` to `http://example.com/page/`. The rule that I am trying to use for this is the following:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)\.(php|html)$ $1/$2/ [R=301,L]`
While this regex correctly detects the page when used with online regex testers like (http://www.regextester.com/) it does not complete in my .htaccess file...

How do I make this regex work in the .htaccess file?

*EDIT*
So now I have this to make sure the actual page is visible:
`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9A-Z]+)\.(php|html)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]`
`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/$ /$1.php [L]`

However, Chrome tells me I have a redirect loop, which I can understand. How would I stop that?

Comment: Wouldn't `http://example.com/page/` give 404 to you?

Comment: @anubhava I plan to use another RewriteRule to make a hidden URL with the correct path, once the browser has been redirected, but of course I need to understand the regex in this to make that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

You can use thed rules:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

This will redirect `/page.php` to `/page/php/` but without other rules in place you will get 404.

Comment: Thank you :) I still have a lot to learn in regards to .htaccess!